# Cordova ios remotebuild no error and no output

Tags: ios, cordova, visual-studio-2015

After the latest set of upgrades (VS2015 Update 3, Cordova 6.xx...) I am trying to build for iOS.  Visual Studio calls my MacInCloud machine and everything appears to build with no errors but I can't find any output from the build.

Comment: Did you check the remote builds folder under /Users/admin/remote-builds